# about opc ua badsecurechannelclosed

Tags: opc-ua

I have two OPC UA servers. One is implemented in Java and the other is implemented in Python. It is normal to connect to the Java OPC UA server with opcuahalper. The same code links to the python server and reports an error badsecurechannelclosed. Are there any friends who encounter this problem? How did you solve it
code below:
// select the best endpoint.
EndpointDescription endpointDescription = CoreClientUtils.SelectEndpoint( serverUrl, UseSecurity );
EndpointConfiguration endpointConfiguration = EndpointConfiguration.Create( m_configuration );

```
        ConfiguredEndpoint endpoint = new ConfiguredEndpoint( null, endpointDescription, endpointConfiguration );

        m_session = await Session.Create(
            m_configuration,
            endpoint,
            false,
            false,
            (string.IsNullOrEmpty( OpcUaName )) ? m_configuration.ApplicationName : OpcUaName,
            60000,
            UserIdentity,
            new string[] { } );
```

Comment: I had a similar issue that got resolved by making use of the timeout property. I also programmed my client to attempt to reconnect if some or all the servers failed to connect.